# SSH gets stuck with no apparent reason

Tags: ssh, openssh

```
OpenSSH_7.6p1, LibreSSL 2.6.2
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/evar/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/evar/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 198.143.181.104 port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/evar/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/evar/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/evar/.ssh/bb_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/evar/.ssh/bb_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6
```

It happened suddenly, with no action done on the server. Unfortunately, I have no access to this VPS without SSH. If it doesn't get fixed, I'd be forced to just delete the VPS :( Any ideas to try?

Update: After some waiting:

```
OpenSSH_7.6p1, LibreSSL 2.6.2
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/evar/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/evar/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 198.143.181.104 port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/evar/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/evar/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/evar/.ssh/bb_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/evar/.ssh/bb_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug3: fd 5 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 198.143.181.104:22 as 'mary'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/evar/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /Users/evar/.ssh/known_hosts:49
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 198.143.181.104
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
Connection closed by 198.143.181.104 port 22
```

PS: Network MTU is 1500.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. A question like this would be more on topic on [unix.se], [sf], or [su].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem went away by itself after some hours. I have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

Restart/reboot your device and it will start work